# Ответам тоже нужны метки

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, ответы

Предлагаю добавить функционал меток для ответов. Это позволит на порядок улучшить качество поиска. Сейчас, по моим ощущениям, поиск больше ориентирован на подбор похожих вопросов, а ответы попадают в выдачу только если в них содержатся искомые фразы. Это не логично, так как пользователь хочет получить ответы, а не вопросы.

Собственно суть моего предложения в том, чтобы переориентировать поиск в большей степени на подбор ответов. Для этого и нужны метки.

Answer (score 7):

ИМХО, абсолютно бессмысленное предложение, в текущем виде. О чём нам говорят метки вопроса? О том, к какой сфере знаний он относится. К какой сфере знаний относится ответ на вопрос? Разумеется, к той же, что и вопрос, иначе это повод для пристального внимания к ответу модераторов. Есть несколько вариантов, при которых, в вашей системе, наборы меток у вопроса и ответа будут различаться:

- Автор ответа считает, что автор вопроса поставил метки неверно. Для
  этого случая есть редактирование меток.
- Частичный ответ на составной вопрос. Но такие вопросы не
  приветствуются и их надо, по возможности, избегать (хоть и не всегда
  выходит), а не поощрять дополнительными инструментами.
- Ответ, выходящий за пределы заданного вопроса. Такие ответы могут
  быть весьма полезны для более полного понимания проблемы
  спрашивающим, но новые темы рассматриваются в них исключительно в
  контексте заданного вопроса и для человека, ищущего информацию по
  метке этой темы, скорее всего окажутся, напротив, слишком
  специфичными, или вовсе бесполезными.

Таким образом, даже если вводить поиск ответов по меткам, то метки должны наследоваться от вопроса, а не назначаться ответом. Кроме того, ища информацию, пользователь склонен формировать запрос именно с точки зрения спрашивающего, что прекрасно помогает находить вопросы, но не ответы на них. Наконец, на один вопрос может быть дано множество ответов, что способствует засорению поиска: Допустим, есть **не интересный** ищущему вопрос и пять ответов на него. Значит, при поиске по вопросам и ответам пользователь получит шесть неподходящих ссылок, вместо одной, при поиске **только** по вопросам.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант: вопрос без ограничений на язык ([tag:любой-язык]), ответ, разумеется, на каком-то конкретном языке. Есть и другие аналогичные случаи. Правда всё равно сомневаюсь, что метки на ответах сколь-нибудь упростят процесс поиска решения.

Comment: Метки ответов должны говорить о том какое решение предлагает ответ. Разумеется ответы должны "наследовать" метки от вопроса, и бессмысленно добавлять к ответу метки типа `C++` если вопрос на тему Си++.

Answer (score 3):

Есть разница между тем, **что ищут** и **чем ищут**.

Люди действительно ищут ответы! Но они не знают заранее, что в них будет, чтобы вводить их фрагменты в поисковик; **всё, что у них обычно есть, это *возникшая проблема***. Поэтому поиск по содержимому ответов реально нужен очень редко и дополнительно расширять его нет серьёзной необходимости.

Comment: А если ищешь, чтобы закрыть вопрос как дубликат? Или то, что уже видел, а сейчас вдруг понадобилось?

Comment: @Qwertiy то всё равно есть текстовый поиск по ответам. Можно даже отдельно убрать вопросы флагом `is:answer`. А метки в этих случаях всё равно не помогут.

Comment: А вот мета-метки помогут. Т. е. вопросам нормальные метки, а ответам мета-метки.

Comment: @Qwertiy например?

Comment: Например, справка, хак, частая-ошибка, особый-случай, предположение и т. д.

Comment: @Qwertiy мысль интересная, стоит развернуть в вопрос, этот (спросив автора) или отдельный. Без автора я уже не могу сказать, развивает ли это его мысль или форкает в совсем другом направлении :)

Comment: Мне кажется, в другом. Хотя общая идея та же - метки на ответах :)

Comment: Да я согласен на разворачивание в вопрос, собственно я и надеялся на коллективную проработку.

Answer (score 3):

Неужели вообще есть смысл что-то *искать* (что в вопросах, что в ответах) на SO?

IMHO человек в поисках ответа обычно вводит какие-то (ключевые?) слова в гугле, а дальше читает одну (реже 2) страницу ответов. Если ничего хорошего не найдено, то тут и наступает черед задать вопрос в SO.

Думаю, что большинство задающих здесь вопросы даже и не пытаются найти ответы, используя строку поиска SO, считая, что непосредственно задать вопрос и получить индивидуальный ответ продуктивнее, нежели копаться в списке, выданном поиском.

Comment: В том то и дело что гугл эффективнее!